# Error 404 en peticiones AJAX desde Android tras cambiar el certificado del servidor

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

Estamos realizando una *app* híbrida con Phonegap y jQuery Mobile que, mediante peticiones ajax, recupera de un servidor externo unos datos en formato JSON para después tratarlos.

Nunca hemos tenido ningún problema ni en iOS ni en Android. Desde que actualizamos el certificado de seguridad del dominio (nos obligan a que el algoritmo de firma sea SHA-256 con cifrado RSA) al que la *App* realiza las peticiones, las conexiones de Ajax nos devuelven un error 404, cuando el día antes estando aún el certificado con firma SHA1 no había ningún problema. En iOS por el contrario sigue sin darnos ningún problema.

¿Alguien podría darme algo de luz al respecto?

Comment: Que raro el caso al cambiar el certificado con SHA-256, como comentario podría decir que pruebes en tu simulador revisando con un proxy (Charles) https://www.charlesproxy.com/, para obtener más información acerca del problema.

Comment: 1. ¿Ha visto qué el servidor escribe en sus registros? Es que error 404 es una respuesta del servidor.

Comment: que version de phonegap/cordova usas? y en que versión de android pruebas? SHA-2 se supone que está soportado desde android 2.3

Comment: Has probado con otro dispositivo, puede que el dispositivo haya memorizado la llave del servidor y ahora que le parece diferente te bote un error, aunque no deberia ser 404 pero mejor descartar.

Tambien revisa a ver si la aplicacion no esta modificando la peticion al realizarla.

Comment: podrías hacer un debug con la consola registrando las peticiones https? para descartar que sea no sea un error 404 sino un bloqueo de recurso lanzado por el navegador

Comment: @Juanma D. ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: Mírate el core plugin whitelist de phonegap, se debe especificar que ámbito quieres que la app pueda acceder externamente, y el servidor debe devolver el origin correcto.
Y si estás acutalizando app yo de tí me miraría otro framework JQueryMobile corre fatal sobre la plataforma phonegap, mirate Ionic o Framework7

Comment: Tendrá algo que ver el dominio y su redirección de http a https?

Comment: Habría que ver en que servidor esta el archivo ya que estuve leyendo que IIS tiene este tipo de problemas . Aqui dejo un par de link con soluciones a un error parecido pero nunca esta de mas probar: [ http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2013/making-xhr-request-to-https-domains-with-winjs/ ] y  [ http://qiku.es/pregunta/119655/ei11-devuelve-el-estado-0-durante-la-operacion-ajax-poste-de-un-iframe-xmlhttprequest-0x2ee4-error-de-red-ie11-returns-status-0-during-ajax-post-operation-from-an-iframe-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ee4 ]

Answer (score 2):

Esto te puede resolver algunas dudas. Copio y pego (traducido por google):

**OS, el navegador y soporte de servidor**

> Android tiene la capacidad técnica de manejo de certificados SHA-256
>   desde la versión 1.0. En la práctica, algunos usuarios pueden
>   encontrar problemas con la validación de certificados que utilizan
>   certificados cruzados (estos certificados de la cadena de ayuda a raíz
>   alternativos). 1.6 mejorado este problema para algunos usuarios, la
>   cuestión se resuelve a partir de la versión 2.2

**Kits de herramientas, bibliotecas, marcos, etc.**

> Soporte para SHA-2 se introdujo en OpenSSL 0.9.8 , pero no está
>   habilitado de forma predeterminada con SSL_library_init (). En 0.9.8,
>   SHA-2 funciones hash deben ser llamados en concreto o utilizando
>   OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms (), que no se pueden desear. OpenSSL 0.9.8o
>   permite a los SHA-2 algoritmos hash en la configuración por defecto.

Referencia [SHA-256 Compatibility](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility#30)